# Authorize webdriver chrome to download many files - python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi stackoverflow community,

I'm quite new to webdriver and Selenium. I'l trying to automate the download of many files but Chrome is always blocking me with the popup "This website is trying to dowload many files" and I have to click on authorise to let it work, but I want to automate this.
I tryed everything but couldn't find the solution to this.
Here is my code :

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
  'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': True,
})
options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
options.add_argument("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
             "download.default_directory": "Your download diectory",
             "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
browser=webdriver.Chrome(<chromdriver.exe path>, options=options)
```